# Uploaded file with white space makes is_resource() fails - php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a script checking if a file exists:

```
function fileExists($url) {
    $fh = fopen($url, 'r');
    if (is_resource($fh)) {
        fclose($fh);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Everything went right until I tried to uploaded files whose name contains white space. Call `$url` the file's url, when I put it in the browser, it displays correctly the file, but `is_resource($fh)` always returns false. Someone could help ?

Comment: Why not using these: `is_file`, `file_exists`, `stat` and more.. http://tr1.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `$fh = fopen($url, 'r');` add this:

```
$parts = pathinfo($url);
$url   = $parts['dirname'].'/'.rawurlencode($parts['basename']);
```

Btw, there is a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16510&edit=1)...